# Problems loading a category in a javascript portofolio list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem. I have this portfolio that loads the categories without reloading the page.

I have created a button with id=produzioni-spot and a javascript that when I click on it will take me to http://onemore.corsidigital.org/produzioni and show me by default the spot tv category, but it does not work, could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? The page is the one mentioned above. Thanks

```html
<div class="edgtf-plf-inner">
<ul>
<li class="edgtf-pl-filter edgtf-pl-current" data-filter="">
<span>VEDI TUTTO</span>
</li>
<li class="edgtf-pl-filter" data-filter=".portfolio-category-a-lungometraggi">
<span>LUNGOMETRAGGI</span>
</li>
<li class="edgtf-pl-filter" data-filter=".portfolio-category-cortometraggi">
<span>CORTOMETRAGGI</span>
</li>
<li class="edgtf-pl-filter" data-filter=".portfolio-category-documentari">
<span>DOCUMENTARI</span>
</li>
<li class="edgtf-pl-filter" data-filter=".portfolio-category-spot-tv">
<span>SPOT TV</span>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  // Select the button with id "produzioni-spot"
  const produzioniBtn = $('#produzioni-spot');

  // Add a listener to listen to the button click
  produzioniBtn.on('click', function() {
    // We redirect the user to the "produzioni" page.
    window.location.href = 'http://onemore.corsidigital.org/produzioni/';

    // We wait a second to make sure that the page has loaded completely.
    setTimeout(function() {
      const categoriaBtn = $('.portfolio-category-spot-tv');
      categoriaBtn.trigger('click');
    }, 1000);
  });
});    `
```

Comment: Hey, what does not work actually?

Comment: also `java` is something completely different than `javascript` and thus unrelated to this question.

Comment: I need to implement a javascript code to a button, in a page X, that when I click on it, it takes me to the portfolio page and makes me see by default the category produzioni for example.